# MvvmCross naming conventions for views

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, naming-conventions, mvvmcross

Where can i find a **detailed** list of the naming conventions of MvvmCross? 
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738780/mvvmcross-naming-conventions) Stack-Overflow Thread but the wiki seems to be disabled. 
Also, the [official documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/) isn't in-depth enough.

I recognized some strange behavior, for example, if I add a new layout without any view / viewmodel class, the app will crash at startup. So does it if i do not start a view models name with "view_".

It took a few hours to find out that the MvvmCross seems to do some magic stuff with layouts at the startup depending on their names, even if they aren't used in code or don't have any view models.

Comment: You may also find the following [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127161/mvvmcross-mvxwindowspagetviewmodel-compilation-error/40186076#40186076) helpful. It describes the different approaches that can be used to link views and view models.

Comment: thanks, thats helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to official mvvm cross documentation:

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/mvvmcross-overview

> One important thing to note, is that by default Views are associated
>   with ViewModels using a naming convention. But using generic is the
>   preferred way. On iOS for example, this is what a View class
>   declaration would look like:
>
> public class MyView : MvxViewController

What other conventions do you have in mind? I found a copy of the missing wiki here https://github.com/rafaelsteil/MvvmCross-Wiki/blob/master/Customising-using-App-and-Setup.md